# Access property in JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm looking to grab the image 'src' within this JSON response, but my trying has left me at a loose end. Any help would be brilliant.

**My Model**

```
  def test
    response = self.class.get("URLFORRESPONSE")
    @elements = response.parsed_response["extractorData"]
    @parsed = @elements.collect { |e| e['src'] }
  end
```

**JSON Response**

```
{
  "extractorData" : {
    "url" : "http://testwebsite.com/",
    "resourceId" : "409417ee21618b70d74b03231a793c2d7",
    "data" : [ {
      "group" : [ {
        "image" : [ {
          "src" : "test0.jpg"
        } ]
      }, {
        "image" : [ {
          "src" : "test1.jpg"
        } ]
      }, {
        "image" : [ {
          "src" : "test2.jpg"
        } ]
      }, {
        "image" : [ {
          "src" : "test3.jpg"
        } ]
      }, {
        "image" : [ {
          "src" : "test4.jpg"
        } ]
      }
```

Comment: `JSON Response` invalid

Comment: Well this is just a sample of the response. What do you mean by invalid?

Comment: Did you parse JSON? How your parsing method looks?

Comment: I'm parsing with HTTParty, I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. It should be:

```
{
    "extractorData": {
        "url": "http://testwebsite.com/",
        "resourceId": "409417ee21618b70d74b03231a793c2d7",
        "data": [{
            "group": [{
                "image": [{
                    "src": "test0.jpg"
                }]
            }, {
                "image": [{
                    "src": "test1.jpg"
                }]
            }, {
                "image": [{
                    "src": "test2.jpg"
                }]
            }, {
                "image": [{
                    "src": "test3.jpg"
                }]
            }, {
                "image": [{
                    "src": "test4.jpg"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

To extract the src's:

```
@parsed = @elements['data'][0]['group'].map{| g | g['image'][0]['src'] }
```

Comment: You may want to consider the case when there is no image or when some of the other JSON is not present. In that case, you could use `dig` or something else...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ugly as hell but i hope this sugestion helps.
Since HTTParty.parsed_response returns a hash and assuming you're using ruby 2.3, you can do:

```
@elements = response.parsed_response["extractorData"]
@elements.dig('data').collect{|h| h.dig('group').collect{|h| h.dig('image').collect{|h| h.dig('src')}}}
```

see it:

```
h = {"extractorData"=>{"url"=>"http://testwebsite.com/", "resourceId"=>"409417ee21618b70d74b03231a793c2d7", "data"=>[{"group"=>[{"image"=>[{"src"=>"test0.jpg"}]}, {"image"=>[{"src"=>"test1.jpg"}]}, {"image"=>[{"src"=>"test2.jpg"}]}, {"image"=>[{"src"=>"test3.jpg"}]}, {"image"=>[{"src"=>"test4.jpg"}]}]}]}}
h.dig('extractorData', 'data').collect{|h| h.dig('group').collect{|h| h.dig('image').collect{|h| h.dig('src')}}}
=> [[["test0.jpg"], ["test1.jpg"], ["test2.jpg"], ["test3.jpg"], ["test4.jpg"]]]
```

Comment: Is the JSON messy/broken? It's from an API so I'll report it to them.

Comment: hummm i see nothing wrong with the json you posted, you can check it on [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)